# Linear Algebra: 2 dimensional V.S.'s and the set of all Linear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $E$ and $F$ be two-dimensional vectors spaces. What is the dimension of $L(E, F)$?

Note: $L(E, F)$ is the set of all linear maps from $E$ to $F$.

What I did: 
 Let $e_1, e_2$ be a basis for two dimensional v.s. $E$.
  Let $f_1, f_2$ be a basis for two dimensional v.a. $F$.
  Let $\phi: E \rightarrow F$.
  Let $\phi (x) = y$ for some $x \in E$, $y \in F$.
  $x= \lambda_1 *e_1 + \lambda_2 * e_2$, $\lambda_i$ scaler.
  $y= \mu_1 * f_1 + \mu_2 * f_2$, $\mu_i$ scaler.
  So, $\phi(\lambda_1 *e_1 + \lambda_2 * e_2) = \phi (x) = y = \mu_1 * f_1 + \mu_2 * f_2$, which is dimension 2.
  So, $L(E, F)$ is of dimension 2.

but it feels like I am missing the point. Is this sufficient, or is my hunch correct? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the dimension of $L(E,F)$ is not 2.

Following your approach, observe that a particular $\phi \in L(E,F)$ is specified by how a basis of $E$ transforms under it. Example:

$$
\phi (e_1) = a_{11} f_1 + a_{12} f_2
$$
$$
\phi (e_2) = a_{21} f_1 + a_{22} f_2
$$

So you need to specify four numbers, the $a_{ij}$, to specify $\phi$. Hence, the dimension of $L(E, F)$ is 4.

You can also think of it in terms of matrices. $L(E,F)$ is isomorphic with $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{K})$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is the field over which $E$ and $F$ are defined.

Comment: Why $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Sorry, thought I read $\mathbb{C}$. Fixing it now.